# Skip the rest of the (included) file in PHP

Tags: php, include

I'm including file `inner.php` in `outer.php`, I have a condition in `inner.php` on which I want to stop executing `inner.php` but NOT the whole script, i.e. I want to jump to the first line in `outer.php` after the inclusion of `inner.php`, and I don't want to wrap all of the code in `inner.php` in an if statement.

Is there a way to do this otherwise?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just do [`return;`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) or [`return($value);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) on top level of the `inner.php` file.

> If called from the global scope, then
>   execution of the current script file
>   is ended. If the current script file
>   was `include()ed` or `require()ed`, then
>   control is passed back to the calling
>   file. Furthermore, if the current
>   script file was `include()ed`, then the
>   value given to `return()` will be
>   returned as the value of the `include()`
>   call.

Comment: Picked for the thoroughness of the explanation, answered *specifically* my question

Answer (score 9):

You can just call `return` in your include file, but if you're having to do this then it suggests there is something wrong with your architecture.  For example, consider this include file:

```
<?php
// include.php
echo "This is my include";
return;
echo "This is after the include";
```

..included on the following page:

```
<?php
// index.php
include('include.php');
```

The output you'd get is: `This is my include`.

Comment: I recommended using a require to stop your page from executing if the include file is not found. I also agree that something is probably wrong with your architecture if you want to do this. Either split up your include files or do conditional testing in your include file.

Answer (score 4):

How about having two files for inner. The first and the second part and place the condition on the second include?

Answer (score 3):

Throw an exception on the point where you want to stop

```
// in inner.php:
// ...some code...

throw new Exception('Error description');

// ...some code which will not always execute...
```

and catch it in the file where you want to resume

```
// in outer.php
try {
    include 'inner.php';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //TODO: add error handling here
}
```

**UPDATE**

Unlike using `return;` as other answers here suggest, using exceptions will break anywhere, even if you're in some function inside inner.php